# Question about quanta and $E=h\nu$

Tags: energy, electromagnetic-radiation, photons

It is my understanding that Planck's major breakthrough was that energy comes in the forms of 'packets' called quanta, each of which has the energy of $6.62e-34$ of one Joule.

By looking at Planck's equation:

$E=h\nu$

We are essentially obtaining the energy of some radiation (i.e. a photon) that has a given frequency by multiplying it by our base 'unit', the quanta.

If this is the case, what is the energy of something that has a non-integer frequency, i.e. 100.5 Hz? Wouldn't this mean we have 100 quanta plus half of one quanta?

Comment: that is not what Planck said, instead energy interaction between the EM field and atomic oscillators occurs in units of $h\nu$ where $\nu$ is the frequency of the interacting EM field whatever that frequency may be.

Comment: The quantum is not $h$ but $h\nu$.

Comment: There is an error in your question. The energy quantum is not equal to $h$ but $h\nu$. This also implies the answer to your question about 100.5 Hz.

Comment: $h$ doesn’t the the same dimensions as energy, and its units aren’t joules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quantum of energy in which the radiation of a frequency $\nu$ can be absorbed or emitted is supposed to be $h\nu$, not $h$. The idea isn't that there exists a universal quantum of energy in multiples of which all light should contain energy. The idea is that the quantum of energy in multiples of which light of a particular frequency $\nu$ contains energy is $h\nu$.

Comment: Then how is the energy discretized? I'm failing to see how Planck's constant differs from a proportionality constant in that case

Comment: @Vranvs Energy is discretized for each frequency. This is to say that radiation of frequency $\nu$ can only come in packets of $h\nu$--there would be no packet of radiation of frequency $\nu$ with an energy $\frac{3}{2}h\nu$. This is precisely the sense in which energy is quantized in quantum mechanics of electromagnetic radiation--a particular quantum for a particular frequency. There is no universal quantum of electromagnetic radiation energy regardless of the frequency of radiation.